# Unable to launch android app from launcher

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am launching my android app from android studio, the app is working fine but unable to launch it from the launcher as it is not showing up there. Looking at other posts it seems that this issue could be because of incorrect AndroidManifest.xml, but mine seems to fine based on other answers.
Below is `AndroidManifest.xml` from my project.

Full file is here -> https://pastebin.com/E7KMxQZD

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Does it show any error when it crashs ?

Comment: App doesn't crash, it is not visible in the launcher like rest of the apps so that I can select and launch it.

Comment: are you making the MainActivity as your Main launcher activity ?

Comment: Yes, MainActivity is Main launcher activity

Comment: i can see that there is no issues with your manifest file  , try to rebuild the project , or invalidate the cache and restart the android studio and let me know if it works

Comment: I tried installing it on different device, it seems to be working fine there, I can see it in the launcher. Issue seems to be with my device.

Comment: Could be yeah , did you try to uninstall and install the app again in your device ?